# kannel service failed to restart

Tags: mysql, linux, kannel

Hello,
                  I have installed gateway 1.5.0(v) with option --with-mysql, and installed kannel rpm kannel-1.4.3, I have been trying to set up dlr-storage using mysql. but im getting error in restart kannel. service failed to restart. but its work with dlr-storage = internal. i was check old posts in kannel user directory and find some related issues but still facing error.

here is my log file of smsbox.

```
2013-09-19 14:50:54 [30003] [0] ERROR: connect failed
2013-09-19 14:50:54 [30003] [0] ERROR: System error 111: Connection refused
2013-09-19 14:50:54 [30003] [0] ERROR: error connecting to server `localhost' at port `13001'
2013-09-19 14:50:54 [30003] [0] PANIC: Couldn't connect to the bearerbox.
2013-09-19 14:50:54 [30003] [0] PANIC: /usr/sbin/smsbox(gw_panic+0x15a) [0x43ddfa]
2013-09-19 14:50:54 [30003] [0] PANIC: /usr/sbin/smsbox(main+0xca0) [0x40e530]
2013-09-19 14:50:54 [30003] [0] PANIC: /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7f2d47967cdd]
2013-09-19 14:50:54 [30003] [0] PANIC: /usr/sbin/smsbox() [0x40d1b9]
2013-09-19 14:50:58 [30040] [0] INFO: Added logfile `/var/log/kannel/smsbox.log' with level `0'.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look this blog post. this may be useful for you.
http://eshaiju.blogspot.in/2013/09/configuring-mysql-dlr-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

FROM THE LOG PROVIDED
make sure bearerbox is running on port 13001 ie in configuration file

```
group=core
smsbox-port=13001
```

and in smsbox conf

```
group = smsbox
bearerbox-host=localhost
bearerbox-port=13001
```